# How to generate hybrid unique address

Tags: smart-contract-wallets

I am making a land registration project. There are total 2 address: (1)owner address (2)land address. So i want to generate a unique identifier that will be formed using above addresses. So that using unique identifier/address can return those addresses.

Comment: you can simply concatenate the two address to have a 40bytes identifier (80 character string)

Comment: @minhhn2910 but this will reveal both addresses. Is there any way that the addresses are hidden in the new identifier?

Comment: you should update your question, it didn't say anything about revealing or privacy

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same encryption as Metamask does (and still supports). Based on a public key you encode the message and the only one who can decrypt is the one with private key.

Take a look on Medium at "Exchanging Encrypted Data on Blockchain Using MetaMask" article. I think this is what you need.